# How to handle React.js nested state?

Tags: reactjs, nested, setstate

I need to have a nested state in my main component. I came up with having the `initialState` which I was going to use for the `reset` feature.

```
constructor() {
  ...
  this.initialState = {
    ...
    employees: {
      manager: {
        name: 'Andrew',
        age: 27
      }
      developer: {
        name: 'David'
        age: 32
      }
    }
    ...
  };

  this.state = this.initialState;
```

But it doesn't work with React. As `setState` can't handle nested properties and both `this.state` and `this.initialState` are just references to the same object. I've tried `spread operator`, `Object.assign` and finally came across a [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

But I still can't understand how to set state in the `constructor` and how to "reset" the `employees` part of the state later on.

Other properties of `state` are flat.

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial state, just use

```
this.state = {
    employees:
      manager: {
        name: 'Andrew',
        age: 27
      }
      developer: {
        name: 'David'
        age: 32
      }
}
```

Then use `setState` to make changes to the state object.

To make changes to nested objects inside the state, We take advantage of object destructuring, by creating a new object which is a copy of the nested employee object. We can make changes to the newly created `employee` object, then save that using `this.setState`

```
resetEmployee() {
    let employee = {...this.state.employee}
    employee.someProperty = someNewValue 
    this.setState({employee}) 
}
```

You could properly abstract this even further, but the example serves the purpose of updating nested objects within the state.

For a deep copy we would look to [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're assigning an empty object to employee(s) before calling setState. I can't understand how this might work.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the example. The point is you update some properties, then pass the updated copy to `setState`.

Comment: Sorry, for the late follow up. The problem is that the `spread` operator doesn't make a "deep" copy of the object. Here is a nice explanation of what I mean http://www.bambielli.com/til/2017-01-29-spread-operator-deep-copy/
My point was to use the `initialState` to not have to reassign each property manually

Comment: I see. Are you able to maybe change the makeup of the state object so you don't have to jump through these hoops?

Comment: Yeah. I read somewhere that fb suggests keeping the state flat but that trows complexity to other parts of the app. 

I just wanna know what's the best practice of handling nested state in React without using Redux or smth.

Comment: I would assist you with this search, since i'm interested to know myself, but i'm currently studying :c

Comment: If I came up with a solution I would post it here. But I hope some experienced devs will get in.

Comment: Do you have a complete example of the data structure you're trying to modify?

Comment: https://github.com/illia108/w_and_b/blob/master/frontend/main/components/Main.jsx